# Combining diacritical marks like the comma above and acute accent with Latin base characters

Tags: html, vba, unicode, ms-word, diacritics

I am developing a solution for MS Word (using VBA) and websites (using HTML/CSS/JS) enabling an efficient typing of character combinations that consist of multiple diacritical marks, such as `œ̣̄̃́`, for example.

A prototype solution has already been implemented, though I've stumbled across one single difficulty that I may not be able to solve without any support.

I need to display [these characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLCzf.png) which consist of the 'combining comma above' (U+0313) and 'combining acute accent' (U+0301). The current result I am getting is a stacked version `c̓́`, though I need the diacritics to be side by side. This is possible with Greek base characters like `ἄ`(03B1+0313+0301) for example, but not with Latin ones.

Even a standalone version exists: ῎(U+1FCE) that is sadly not combinable.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Just curious; which characters in which languages have that diacritic?

Comment: @MrLister some latin- and greek-based languages make use of these diacritics, in order to specify the exact pronounciation. But I have no linguistic backround tbh, so don't take this at face value; I'm just here to programm this

Comment: For the specific case where the combo looks like U+1FCD or U+1FCE, *in Word* you can use an EQ field, e.g. { EQ \o(a,῎)} or using a Math Equation. e.g. copy the following MathML and paste it into a Word document, then make it Inline: <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mover accent="true"><mtext>a</mtext><mo>&#x1FCE;</mo></mover></math>. The first of those won't help you on the Web, but the MathML representation might, depending on the browser (my test put the accent too high). Perhaps CSS can help. Experiments using MathML multiple accent characters not so successful.

Comment: BTW I suspect a lot of people here would not regard this as a "programming question" as far as SO is concerned - possibly why it has been downmarket.

Comment: okay I am going to try this stuff out and update this thread based on my findings; thanks everyone!

Comment: @MrLister the italian language uses it (or at least has used it the past)

Comment: @MrLister I found the letters C and G with comma and acute accent above in the orthography used by the 
Centro di dialettologia e di etnografia (CDE) for dialects of Lombard spoken in Switzerland (example: https://www4.ti.ch/fileadmin/DECS/DCSU/CDE/pdf/pubblicazioni/LSI-Guida_grafica_consultazione.pdf ) as well as one orthography for Ladin (see http://diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1336549/FULLTEXT01.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reaching out to [the Unicode Consortium](https://home.unicode.org/) this was the answer of one of their representatives:

> I checked the Unicode code chart and consulted with other Unicode experts. The code point that should be used, in the view of the experts, is: U+0313 COMBINING COMMA ABOVE.
> In the Phonetic Symbol Guide, the entry for “apostrophe” mentions its use for palatalization (by Slavicists), besides its use for ejectives or glottalized consonants, and states it can appear following the symbol or over the symbol.
> However, I tried out U+0313 on various fonts, and see fonts don't work as you wish: the acute and COMBINING COMMA ABOVE stack (or collide), instead of appearing beside one another. To rectify the situation, you should contact the font providers and ask them to adjust the font - or do it yourself if you have the tools.
> I hope this is helpful. (Using an already encoded  Unicode code point will save 2+ years of waiting for a new character.)

Our solution to this problem was to create a custom font that moves the U+1FCE character on top of the base character, effectively making it a *combining* one. This font will also be used for our web applications, so not just MS-Word.

Comment: I think this is a general problem that might not be practical to address as just a font issue, since other diacritic combinations do stack vertically. This particular combination of comma and acute accent above should maybe be added to Unicode. Would you happen to have textual sources showing this diacritic? I already found examples of usage in Lombard and Ladin (see comment under the original question above), but more would be useful for writing a proposal. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Word, Unicode 0315 is known as a 'combining comma above right'. The reverse form of this is Unicode 0314, which is known as a 'combining reversed comma above'. There are also Unicode 0312, known as a 'combining turned comma above' and Unicode 0313, known as a 'combining comma above'.

Comment: Why do you say "In Word"? These are the offical codepoint names according to Unicode, nothing nothing to do with MS Word...

Comment: @macropod Well yes, that is true. But the 'combining reversed comma above' (0314) is still not the same as the required 'combining comma above left' (non-existent) as it is just the mirrored version of the 'combining comma above right' (0314), isn't it?

Comment: @macropod Also when combining the mirrord comma with e.g. an acute tone mark the [diarcital marks interfere with each other](https://imgur.com/a/jDOuvsu)

Comment: I said "In Word' because that's what you see in the Insert|Symbol dialogue box for these Unicode characters.

Comment: @macropod Yeah I got that; still does not solve the problem unfortunately. Or was this a reply to user-lenz

Comment: My previous comment was in reply to lenz - as I'd have thought was quite obvious. Regarding the conflicting diacritics, the behaviour is to some extent dependent on the order in which they're inserted. For example, you can insert Unicode 0315 followed by Unicode 0301 - the latter appears above the former - but not the other way around.

Comment: @macropod Sure thing! I still need to display the comma and the acute above the base character, but **on the same height**. For example [like this](https://imgur.com/a/COnPTT9) (acute tone mark & comma above right), but with the diacritcal marks swapped (so _comma above left_ & acute tone mark).

Comment: For something like that you might use Unicode 0107 (small C with acute) preceded by Unicode 0315 (combining comma above right).

Comment: @macropod Sadly no, as the 0107 (small C with acute) character behaves the same as combining the seperate characters (small c + combining acute accent). The important part here is the difference between the combining acute accent and the combining acute tone mark. The tone mark allows another combining character on the same height, what raises the earlier described interference problem when using the regular (-not left-) comma above. Using the acute accent (pre-combined as in 0107 or manually combined [0063 + 0301]) does not allow another combining diacritical mark on the same height, see `ć̓`

Comment: The sequence I suggested places the diacritic comma on the same level as the acute. Do make sure both employ the same font & point size.

Comment: @macropod can you paste in the result as I did in my previous message? Because I tried it again, using the exact sequence you suggested an keep getting this `ć̓` as the result. Idenpendently of the way I combine this character (with my macro or manually via Insert > Symbol) the result is the same.

Comment: Insert the Unicode 0107 first, then move the insertion point back one position before inserting the Unicode 0315. That way you'll get ̕ć (but with the result displayed better than it does here - both the ̕ and the ́ will be displayed at the same height).

Comment: @macropod Oh I am so sorry, I was using 0314 the entire time; now I see what you're describing. This does raise another problem though, inserting the 0315 character before 0107 will bind it to the previous character (if it exists). So if a word starts with ̕ć thats no problem but as soon as the 'c'-character is within a word like for example 'ma̕ćro' you can see how it will be bound to the 'a'-character in this case

Comment: Try Maʼćro, with the 'a' horizontal spacing condensed by 1/6th the point size and the 'ʼ' horizontal spacing condensed by 1/4th the point size. FWIW, I know of no latin-based or greek-based language that makes use of such a diacritic combination. Greek has its own extensive character set that includes all diacritic combinations known to me.

Comment: @macropod I've noticed, that many greek characters have this combination already, for example ὤ (U+1F64). Using Latin base characters and combining diacritical marks (as well as the combining acute and not the tone mark) causes the combination to not be displayed as desired: a̓́ (0061+0313+0301).

However, with Greek base characters the desired result is achievable: ἄ (03B1+0313+0301) or ἔ (03B5+0313+0301)

In addition to that a precomposed version of this exists as a regular character: ῎ (1FCE) that is sadly not combinable.

Comment: So why are you trying to combine characters when all valid combinations are already available as single characters?

Comment: @macropod Well it is **not** possible for latin base characters. So a regular 'c' or a 'g' is neither combinable with ῎ (U+1FCE) (*obviously, as it is a standalone character and not a combining one*) nor with the 'combining comma above' (U+0313) + 'combining acute accent' (U+0301) in order to get the desired result (which is ῎ on top of them).

Comment: And who uses these obscure characters?

Comment: @macropod The comma above is quite usual in the elder versions of phonological and phonetical transkriptions. The whole traditional romance philology (dialectology) used it, naturally mainly in combination with the velars K and G that become palatal. In combination with the accent it means "palatalization and affricativation". So yes, it is used in many texts (s. above). It is quite frequent.